# 3d plot with multiple lines showing the projection on the xy plane

Tags: matplotlib, plot, fill

I was wondering how to have a 3d plot with multiple lines showing the projection on the xy plane by means of something like `fill_between` but in 3D. I have here a sample code.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8),subplot_kw={'projection': '3d'})

for i in np.arange(0.0,1,0.1):
    x1=np.arange(0,1-i+0.01,0.01)
    y1=1.0-i-x1
    def z_func(x,y,z):
        return x+y**2+0.5*z #can be any fn
    coordinates3= [[i,j,1-i-j] for j in np.arange(0,1-i+0.01,0.01)]
    z1=np.array([z_func(*k) for k in coordinates3])
    ax.plot(x1,y1,z1)

ax.view_init(azim=10,elev=20)
plt.show()
```

[image]

I'd like to have each line 'projected' on the xy plane, with a shaded filling in between the curve and its projection. Anybody knows a quick way?

Comment: You need a [`Poly3DCollection`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d.Poly3DCollection.html) with the two points on the x-y-plane added to each set of vertices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the suggestion in the comments of @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, I was able to write a solution. I came up with this:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8),subplot_kw={'projection': '3d'})

prop_cycle = plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle']
colors = prop_cycle.by_key()['color']

for color,i in enumerate(np.arange(0.0,1,0.1)):
    x1=np.arange(0,1-i+0.01,0.01)
    y1=1.0-i-x1
    def z_func(x,y,z):
        return x+y**2+0.5*z #can be any fn
    coordinates3= [[i,j,1-i-j] for j in np.arange(0,1-i+0.01,0.01)]
    z1=np.array([z_func(*k) for k in coordinates3])
    verts=[[(k[1],k[2],z_func(*k)) for k in coordinates3]]
    verts[0].insert(0,(coordinates3[0][1],coordinates3[0][2],0))
    verts[0].insert(0,(coordinates3[-1][1],coordinates3[-1][2],0))
    poly = Poly3DCollection(verts,color=colors[color])
    poly.set_alpha(0.2)
    ax.add_collection(poly)
    ax.plot(x1,y1,z1,linewidth=10)

ax.view_init(azim=10,elev=20)
plt.show()
```

[image]

One thing that puzzles me is that the shade doesn't get the color of the line and that I had to supply it myself. If you remove the `color=colors[color]` in the `Poly3DCollection` you always get blue shades, whereas the lines automatically get the different colors, as one can see in the question. Anybody knows a reason for this?